# How to turn off syntax highlighting in console? Windows 10 2020

Tags: powershell

I've been trying to turn OFF the syntax high lighting but using examples here all I get are errors:
Set-PSReadLineOption : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'TokenKind'.
At line:1 char:22
+ Set-PSReadlineOption -TokenKind Comment -ForegroundColor $Host.UI.Raw ...
+                      ~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Set-PSReadLineOption], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NamedParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.SetPSReadLineOption

Since I don't have what it takes to comment I have to ask a NEW question..

Answer (score 2):

The syntax changed in a recent update. The old syntax will now give you a error message. So now you have to use this:

```
Set-PSReadLineOption -Colors @{None='black';Comment='black';Keyword='black';String='black';Operator='black';Variable='black';Command='black';Parameter='black';Type='black';Number='black';Member='black'}
```

Attribution: @Triplee